# match zero or one pattern occurence

Tags: python, glob

Suppose I have next files:

```
/path/to/file/a.png
/path/to/file/a_match_me.png
/path/to/file/a_dont_match_me.png
```

I want to match 2 files

```
/path/to/file/a.png
/path/to/file/a_match_me.png
```

but do not match `/path/to/file/a_dont_match_me.png`

So, I need regexp, something like `/path/to/file/a[zero or one occurence of _match_me].png`

Can I do it, using `glob` library in python?

Comment: What is the input data ? a string? or the result of a command ? show us please.
Could you also explain the pattern you want to match for the first file ? any first file/line is ok ? and for the second file should always have "_match_me" in the filename ?

Comment: `glob.glob` finds files in directory, that match with pattern. I want my pattern to be `a[zero or one occurence of _match_me]`. It's equal to `a(_match_me){0,1}` in regexp, but it doesn't work with `glob`

Comment: You can't do this with standard fnmatch-style shell globs (as distinct from bash's "extglob" extended syntax), and those are what the `glob` library supports.

Answer (score 2):

You would have a hard time doing this with the built-in Python glob library, but you could do this with a third party library.

The python library [wcmatch](https://pypi.org/project/wcmatch/) can be used for the described case above. Full disclosure, I am the author of the mentioned library.

Below we use the `GLOBSTAR` flag (`G`) to match multiple folders with `**` and the `EXTGLOB` flag (`E`) to use extended glob patterns such as `!()` which excludes a file name pattern. We use the `globfilter` command which can filter a full path names with glob patterns. It is kind of like `fnmatch`'s filter, but does full paths.

```
from wcmatch import glob

files = [
    "/path/to/file/a.png",
    "/path/to/file/a_match_me.png",
    "/path/to/file/a_dont_match_me.png"
]

print(glob.globfilter(files, '**/a!(_dont_match_me).png', flags=glob.G | glob.E))
```

Output

```
['/path/to/file/a.png', '/path/to/file/a_match_me.png']
```

You could also glob these files directly from the file system:

```
from wcmatch import glob

glob.glob('**/a!(_dont_match_me).png', flags=glob.G | glob.E)
```

Hopefully this helps.